# TypeScript configuration

Tags: javascript, typescript, compilation, config, tsconfig

I'm new to the world of typeScript, hence I'm having some configuration issues. The problem is that some methods are not working even though they theoretically should. Currently my typeScript config looks as follows:

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "ES2015.Collection",
      "ES2015.Iterable",
      "ES2016.Array.include",
      "ES2017.Object",
      "ES5",
      "ES6",
    ],
  }
}
```

Everything seems to be fine besides the fact that when I try to use for example Number.isInteger() method or Array.entries() method following error occurs:

> Property 'isInteger' does not exist on type 'NumberConstructor'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2015' or later.

The same happens with .entries(). Can anyone help?

Comment: Your `lib` should probably just be `dom` and `es6`.

Comment: Saddly this solution didn't help either :(

Answer (score 0):

The following is from the Typescript playground.  If you follow the link and toggle the options, you can figure out what you need. Looks like you need more of ES2015, they show as errors when target is ES5.

```
console.log(Number.isInteger(1))
const arr = [1, 2, 3]
console.log(arr.entries())
```

**Output**

```
"use strict";
console.log(Number.isInteger(1));
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(arr.entries());
```

**Compiler Options**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "target": "ES2017",
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

**Playground Link:** [Provided](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=2#code/MYewdgziA2CmB00QHMAUA5ArgWwEawCd4BLCASTABdZlDUBGASkYChRJKACAQwIM4C8nANr0ANJwBMEgMwBdNuChxEKVLyKwqBYrAipmLIA)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I'll definetly try it out!

Comment: Yeah didnt work :(

Comment: Didn't work isn't very helpful.  Please explain what you tried and what results you received

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I tried the settings suggested by TS in playground, which you posted above but they didn't work.

Comment: I just checked the playground and turned off all options except the ones the playground lets me set that match yours and it works (even for ES2015/ES6).  It only ceases to work in the playground if the 'noLib' option is selected, which disables default libs that are normally selected for target (and ignores `libs` option).  I suspect that your libs are overriding and turning off the defaults that work.  Try removing them all and adding one by one to see what effect that has.  I suspect you have too many, if you features from ES2017 why not just say `ES2017`?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! In my case also es2017 option did not work for some reason. I have no idea why, but only after I set the target to esNext the above mentioned methods like .isInteger and .entries() started working. Now I can even set the target to es2017 and it also works so... no idea what was the problem honestly.

Comment: Ok turns out its not working again but I think I found the issue. I think for some reason my tsc does not pick up on tsconfig. Any idea how o solve this? Tried looking it up, solutions werent helpful though

Comment: It should be in the working directory (project root normally) or specified on the command line (`tsc -p path/to/tsconfig.json`).  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: that was exactly the problem, when you provide an input in the consoe tsconfig file is overridden, thanks for support!